# Group Theory innG is normal subgroup of autG

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Any hints for proving that **innG $\triangleleft$ autG for any group G**.

where innG(Inner automorphism of G) and autG(Automorphism of G)
and H $\triangleleft$ K (H is normal subgroup of K).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have $\tau \in \text{inn}(G)$. Then there is a $g \in G$ such that $\tau(h) = ghg^{-1}$ for all $h \in G$. If $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(G)$, can you express $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}(h)$ as an inner automorphism (by an element related to $g$ somehow)?